# Mercurial Log: how to show renames?

Tags: logging, mercurial, rename

I want to see information on renamed files for the `hg log` command, when invoked for the repository root (i.e. not for a specific file). Are there any options to `hg log` which will display this information? Ideally, I'd like `hg log --stat` information to be extended by the information on renames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg log --template "{node|short}: {file_copies}\n"`

Beware: file_copies keyword has small problem, contrary to others lists, compare output

```
>hg log --template "{node|short}: {file_copies}\n"
cbbb1b9c321d: fileB.txt (file2.txt)fileC.txt (file3.txt)
1589ead8667d:
```

*(file2 was renamed to FileB, file3 - to fileC)*

and

```
>hg log --template "{node|short}: {files}\n"
cbbb1b9c321d: file2.txt file3.txt fileB.txt fileC.txt
1589ead8667d: .hgignore file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```